# Number of ways to distribute n identical balls amongst $k$ bins

Tags: probability, combinatorics

So I've heard different responses from a lot of my friends when we were discussing this, and no answer seems to make intuitive sense to me. I thought it would be $n^k$, as this would represent the fact that each of the $k$ bins could contain up to n balls, but this is apparently incorrect.

I've googled this question nearly every time it comes up in my problem sets, so any clarity or intuition on this could help me a lot! Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your answer is correct if the balls are distinguishable.  If not, with three balls and two bins there are only four choices: $0+3, 1+2, 2+1, 3+0$ while you are claiming eight.  Since the balls are identical, just line them up and put dividers between them to show when you move from one bin to another.  This is a [stars and bars problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics))

Answer (score 0):

Counting the possible combinations of k-1 items from n+1 items